# Is there a way to discard the event object data received by a function from an event handler?

Tags: javascript, event-handling

I have an issue with a function that is being called both manually in the code and by an event handler. This leads to the first argument being the event object in one case and a variable that I have set up in another.

```
function updateProducts(utype,rep)
```

This function takes the first variable it receives and shoves it under the labeled "utype" argument, and then it takes the second variable and shoves it under the "rep" labeled argument.

This leads to utype = event object or [Object object] in some cases. I would like to avoid this and by somehow discarding the event object from the event handler. Is this possible ?

Comment: Don't install the `updateProducts` function itself as the event handler, but a `function(event) { updateProducts(…); }` where you can call it with whatever values you like.

Comment: Like a delegation type of thing, good thinking, what I did as a temporary workaround is i assigned the event as the first argument, and every time i call the function from the code i just set the first argument as null and fill in the variables i need for the second. But your idea is also very good ! Thanks